# Loop through output of query

Tags: sql, bash, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this code that iterates through all values returned by a query -

```
psql -h host -U user db -t -c "query" | while read bucket_name_var ; 
do
if [ ! -z "$bucket_name_var" ]
then
<code>
fi
done
```

But I have this code that doesn't. It only runs the loop one time (for the first value returned from a query) -

```
snowsql -u user -w warehouse -d db -s schema -a account -r role -q "query" -o timing=false -o header=false -o friendly=false -o output_format=plain | while read bucket_name_var ; 
do
if [ ! -z "$bucket_name_var" ]
then 
<code>
fi 
done
```

How do I get the second script to run through all values like the first one?

Comment: What exactly does the `snowsql` command output?

Comment: It could be bucket_name_var has only one value when you are using snowsql.

Comment: @Anand No, it has the same values as the first query

Comment: Without knowing what's different between the two loops, we can only guess blindly. Does something in the loop read from stdin? Otherwise, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed (i.e. remove everything irrelevant from the code or replace it with dummy code, and post it so other people can run it and see the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working fine for me:

```
$ snowsql -c <myconnection> -q "SELECT * FROM CITIBIKE_TRIPS LIMIT 10" -o timing=false -o header=false -o friendly=false -o output_format=plain | while read line ; do echo $line; done
```

I get as output:

```
$ snowsql -c sfcsupport2 -q "SELECT * FROM CITIBIKE_TRIPS LIMIT 10" -o timing=false -o header=false -o friendly=false -o output_format=plain | while read line ; do echo $line; done
D8F945DF62B40435 docked_bike 2021-02-19 15:38:40.000 2021-02-19 16:03:09.000 Rogers Ave & Sterling St 3696 Henry St & Atlantic Ave 4531 40.663061 -73.953874 40.69089272 -73.99612349 member
D1E270A15A1D214F docked_bike 2021-02-20 13:52:47.000 2021-02-20 14:02:20.000 Grand St & Havemeyer St 5267 Nassau Ave & Newell St 5623 40.712868 -73.956981 40.724812564 -73.947526217 member
42F96D9314774473 docked_bike 2021-02-25 10:07:22.000 2021-02-25 10:35:40.000 Grand St & Havemeyer St 5267 Broadway & E 22 St 6098 40.712868 -73.956981 40.740343 -73.989551 member
3ED7E351A3A199EF docked_bike 2021-02-25 08:21:58.000 2021-02-25 08:53:00.000 Rogers Ave & Sterling St 3696 Union Ave & N 12 St 5411 40.663061 -73.953874 40.71924 -73.95242 member
FADEDDEDDE1C9759 docked_bike 2021-02-24 08:58:25.000 2021-02-24 09:07:53.000 W 56 St & 10 Ave 6955 Madison Av & E 51 St 6659 40.768254 -73.988639 40.75863 -73.97513 member
51836F916E1C8EF3 docked_bike 2021-02-25 19:10:10.000 2021-02-25 19:50:07.000 Great Jones St 5636 Park Pl & Vanderbilt Ave 4083 40.727434 -73.99379 40.6767 -73.969024 casual
15A20E9DCA3A2BC5 docked_bike 2021-02-18 08:51:50.000 2021-02-18 09:01:50.000 W 56 St & 10 Ave 6955 Madison Av & E 51 St 6659 40.768254 -73.988639 40.75863 -73.97513 member
A9251AB641D35BCC docked_bike 2021-02-09 14:28:12.000 2021-02-09 14:39:37.000 Sterling St & Bedford Ave 3665 Park Pl & Vanderbilt Ave 4083 40.662705 -73.956911 40.6767 -73.969024 member
C551B9108B71F18F docked_bike 2021-02-17 08:26:35.000 2021-02-17 08:49:31.000 24 Ave & 26 St 7152 Madison Av & E 51 St 6659 40.774591 -73.918544 40.75863 -73.97513 member
7093DCCCB756D8AE docked_bike 2021-02-19 14:46:14.000 2021-02-19 14:57:29.000 W 56 St & 10 Ave 6955 W 59 St & 10 Ave 7023 40.768254 -73.988639 40.770513 -73.988038 member
$
```

I don't understand why would you need to check if the line returned is not empty like (! -z $line) when an empty line wouldn't be displayed in the first place.
Posting a sample output of the query and what exactly you would like to verify would probably help.